# How to load tiles of a specific area in OpenLayers 3 using a bounding box

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have built a simple OpenLayers 3 map, see below for code:

HTML code:

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map{
     width:100%;
     height:800px;
}
```

OpenLayers map initialization code:

```
var map;    
function init(){
    map = new ol.Map({
        target:'map',
        renderer:'canvas',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            center:[-8015003.33712,4160979.44405],
            zoom:5
        })
    });  
    var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    map.addLayer(newLayer);
}
```

Now my map loads just fine, what I would really like to do is, I would like to have only a specific area loaded, for which I need a bounding box, I would like to load the the bounding box for **[THIS](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=14/45.1354/42.0239)** area. But I am new to OpenLayers 3, so I tried and I just couldn't make the bounding box.

Can somebody help me make the bounding box please?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by defining an [Extent](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/apidoc/ol.html#.Extent) at map creation using

```
//Lower left corner of BBOX
var coord1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([45.1101 , 41.9668])
//Upper right corner of BBOX
var coord2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([45.1606, 42.0810])

map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:900913',
        center:[-8015003.33712,4160979.44405],
        zoom:5
    }),
    //       minx       miny       maxx       maxy
    extent: [coord1[0], coord1[1], coord2[0], coord2[1]
});
```